# Android crash happening in some background apps

Tags: android

I'm facing a very annoying android crash that happens in around 1% of PRODUCTION the sessions with the app ALWAYS in the background.

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.android.server.wm.TaskDisplayArea.getDisplayId()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2054)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7755)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

From this stack is clear that it comes from an internal android MainLooper operation... but the lack of extra information difficult for me to discover WHAT exactly

does anyone know what is this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Perhaps show us the code around the error

Comment: It is not simpe like this, this error is thown in a INTERNAL ANDROID THREAD... all the methods in that stack are from ANDROID OS, It is happening in production and in 1% of sessions so I have no idea WHAT IS MY CODE AROUND IT

Comment: I'm getting exact report a bunch too.  It only appears to happen on Android 11, and only on motorola devices (moto g8, moto g 5G plus, motorola edge, motorola g(8) power).  It happens 89% of the time in the background.

Comment: Yeah I have this too, also only on Motorola Android 11 but about 40% of the time in the background. Did you solve this at all?

Comment: I have the exact smae problem. do you have some news about it?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Android 11 (SDK 30).
Did you find any solution to this? Help please.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a whole lot we can do with this level of information. The only thing I can see is this:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.android.server.wm.TaskDisplayArea.getDisplayId()' on a null object reference
```

At some stage, your code is calling (or using a library which calls) `getTaskDisplayArea()` in `com.android.server.wm`. This returns null. It then tries to use this to `getDisplayId()`.

(The rest of the error lines there just indicate it's not in the main thread)

It's likely that wherever you're using the `TaskDisplayArea` (or the library that calls it) is being called when the UI has been destroyed or has yet to be created.

The rarity indicates it probably is a total background restart of your UI/display elements... if I had to guess maybe caused by Android OS memory cleanup triggers while multitasking, or the user changing orientation repeatedly, etc etc.

If you give more details about where you've used the `com.android.server.wm` code or layouts you can probably get more help for how to make this background-thread-proof. Depending on what you're actually doing you might end up just catching the exception & retrying later, but some views will allow you to post info to the main thread and I don't know if `TaskDisplayArea` does.

Comment: From the stack trace, you can see it is system code that calls, and so it's unlikely to be OPs code responsible. I'm also struggling with how to debug or prevent this issue.

Comment: Yeah the comments about it being motorola only weren't there when I did this answer. I suspect that you'll need to do a bug report to motorola.

Comment: HI @user3252344 do you know how can I do a bug report to Motorola?

Comment: Hell @pablobaldez, I'm experiencing the same issue. Have you already reported the bug? If yes, do you mind to share the link please?

Comment: hi @Kikiwa I don't how and where could I report this issue. do you know?

Comment: I didn't find a issue tracker, maybe you can start with a chat or a tweet to ask if there is one or where to contact a dev https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/mcp/contactus Good luck!

Comment: Any update on this problem? I have the same.

Comment: I am facing the same. I'd appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I found that the project had a notification icon file in res/drawable-v24/ic_launcher_foreground.xml. The crashing stopped when I moved the .xml associated with v24 in the drawable res folder.